# Resistor's Resistance - Reading the colors

Tags: resistors, resistance

From which side should I start reading the color bands for calculating the resistance of a resistor?
I have already tried, but I don't know anything about it.

Comment: start from the bottom and read by working your way up

Comment: You're going to have to provide some more detail. Perhaps include a circuit diagram, and describe your method for calculating the resistance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Read the color code on a resistor?

Comment: From what information are you attempting to calculate the resistance?  Material properties?  The required value for some particular function in a circuit?

Comment: U people are not understanding,what I mean is that to calculate resistance from which side should I start from left or right,how do I know which side is the starting side to calculate the resistance

Comment: " You people are not understanding". You are the one who is not properly understanding what you are asking and how to ask a question here. Then how come we understand?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_color_code

Answer (score 3):

Take the resistor, hold it horizontally with your fingers. 
Notice the color strips. Always keep Gold,Silver or large blank space to your right hand side. 
Start counting from your left. 
The value = xy*10^(z) (+-)(5% or 10% or 15%)
x, y and z are the values of the colors.

Comment: most resistor colour code charts have a diagram showing the various options...